# Json response error JSON.parse: unexpected end of data error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi friends I am having a weired error I am using ajax to get the data from other file that is using php query it returns a json_encode but json.parse is having a problem......
here is my code....

```
$.get("pgs/dpg.php",{pg:"18", type:"rec", obs_code:$("#obs_code").val(),lib_code:$("#lib_code").val()},function(data){
obj = JSON.parse(data);
 $("#obs_focused").val(obj.obs_focused);
 $("#obs_projects").val(obj.obs_projects);
 });
```

and here is my php file.....

```
  switch($_REQUEST['type']){
  case 'rec' :

   $sql=mysql_query("select obs_attendance_punctuality,  obs_general_fitness,  obs_listening, 
          obs_independence, obs_special_mention, obs_participation,
          obs_responsibility, obs_awards, obs_nobooks, obs_focused, obs_care_env, obs_projects,
          obs_hand_control, obs_home_read, obs_workshop_parents, obs_workshop_child,
          obs_field_trips, obs_homework, obs_eating, obs_batroom, obs_relation, obs_themes, 
          obs_courtesy, obs_instructions, obs_initiative, obs_alertness, obs_descipline, obs_assembly,
          obs_interest, obs_grade, obs_undergarments, obs_general_hygiene, ".$xtflds."
          obs_clarity, obs_clarity_rem, obs_tone_pitch, obs_tone_pitch_rem, obs_confidence,
          obs_confidence_rem, obs_hand_coordination, obs_hand_coordination_rem, obs_eye_coordination,
          obs_eye_coordination_rem, obs_body_language, obs_body_language_rem, obs_enthusiasm_interest,
          obs_enthusiasm_interest_rem, obs_facial_expressions, obs_facial_expressions_rem,
          obs_content, obs_content_rem, obs_vocabulary, obs_vocabulary_rem, obs_body_posture,
          obs_body_posture_rem, remarks
          from obsr
          where obs_code =".$_REQUEST['obs_code']);

          $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
          echo json_encode($data);


  return; 
  break;
        }
```

Please help me out on this.........

console.log(data)

is outputting this......

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input 
console.log(data) 
ReferenceError: data is not defined
message: "data is not defined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Its not working.............

Comment: We need to see what is outputted by the php file, it is most likely invalid in some way.

Comment: Also, i would consider it unsafe to use `JSON.parse()` without specifically setting the dataType of your ajax request to `text`. It would be better to use `$.getJSON` and not use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: write console.log(data) and check the console ,show us the JSON string

Comment: the php file returns an array....why is it invalid....????

Comment: @user3091928 because it is? that's exactly what the error message you are getting means.

Comment: Again, we need to *see* it. Then we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @anand4tech....where to write console...m new to jquery... can u tell me that.........

Comment: ehrm... dev tools from the browser? F12 on ie, Ctrl+Shift+J on Chrome (for windows) ?

Comment: Try running your JSON output through: http://jsonlint.com/, it will tell you where the problem is in your JSON document

Comment: you will have to do the console.log(data) inside the callback you have on the get function:
`$.get("pgs/dpg.php",{pg:"18", type:"rec", obs_code:$("#obs_code").val(),lib_code:$("#lib_code").val()},function(data){ console.log(data); });`

Comment: console.log(data) is giving me..... an empty string

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()`...

In PHP, please be sure to use

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

If you use it already, and your php file does not output anything else before

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

, it *has* to work, even if $data happens to be null... :-)

Comment: where i have to define 


header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: And, I agree with other comments, please spend some minutes installing and learning a browser debugger (firebug, chrome developer tool, ...)

Comment: Please see the first line I just added to my answer; this is probably the solution for your problem :-)

Comment: in this way.............$.getJSON("pgs/dpg.php",{pg:"18", type:"rec", obs_code:$("#obs_code").val(),lib_code:$("#lib_code").val()},function(data){
                                

    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    //alert(obj);




            $("#obs_attendance_punctuality").val(obj.obs_attendance_punctuality);
                                 $("#obs_general_fitness").val(obj.obs_general_fitness);     });

Comment: Try to write console.log(data); *before* obj = JSON.parse(data); so we can see what we receive in PHP...

Comment: Then your server script (PHP file) probably outputs an empty JSON. Try to put the same url you call (something like "pgs/dpg.php?pg=18&type=rec&obs_code=...&lib_code=...") and try to understand if it behaves as you expect...

Answer (score 0):

You have to mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array. Because mysql_fetch_array simply return array of values not a key-value pair.

And also ensure there is no printed statement after echoing output. So that, You have to use exit() or die() instead of "return" statement.

And make sure your php code print encoded json properly. You can check this, firebug or chrome developer tool.

Comment: @user3091928, Have you checked XHR response body in chrome developer tool? If yes, then post that response body.

Comment: this is the response
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'obs_attendance_punctuality' of null